# Does there exist an open source p2p offsite backup system?

Tags: backup, p2p

It occurred to me last night that I want to do offsite backups of my personal data, and would be willing to donate hard drive space to the cause. So I was thinking I'd write a p2p system where anybody could join and store whatever they wanted (heavily encrypted and all that) as long as they donated drive space to the cause for others to use. I was planning my design when I thought maybe somebody had already done this? Ring a bell?

If not maybe I'll start the project.

Comment: Will you trust your data to be safe (from deletion or disaster) in the hands of a total stranger? Even if shared with multiple people, what if they decide they want to stop using that system and delete your backups? I think such system does not exist because it's not a really good idea.

Comment: This idea has been floating around for a long time and many people have implemented more or less similar systems. The problem is exactly like David said, people who are serious about backups would have invested in more reliable solutions especially since hard disks were so cheap before the floods in Thailand.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite simple because in all modern p2p system you donate a part of your hdd to be occupied. It depends if your data is interesting enough to share. Hence emule and bittorrent is a legit answer.

Comment: except it doesn't actually solve the problem I'm trying to solve in a useful way. But thanks for the answer.